# Where can I find a replacement sash for my double-hung window?

Tags: windows

I have a broken inner pane on the lower sash and would like to find a replacement sash. I am having trouble identifying the manufacturer.

I am guessing it is a 26 inch square window since it measures 25 1/4 wide by 26 3/8 tall.

Here are the markings on the window:

> PAT (VA), SPEC NFRC, SERIES VWDH, MST 3856,PAT M 490, NFRC 100-200, and PAT-M-040.

I can post photos if that's needed. Can you help?

Comment: How can it be 26" square if one side is 25 1/4" ?

Comment: Nominal size isn't particularly useful information. We can deduce that from the dimensions. Wood? Vinyl? Aluminum?

Comment: Might be an [Andersen Narroline](https://parts.andersenwindows.com/search.jsp?fs_0_UnitNumberandSize=3856+Cottage&category=w_dh_psnl_sash). Did you search that code?

Comment: I bought Kolbe & Kolbe sash and jamb replacement kits.  I live in an old house, and of the 17 windows, 2 of them are a standard size.  The rest I custom ordered.

Comment: Can you post photos?